# magento admin confirmation popup on invoice creation

Tags: magento

I am trying to add a confirmation popup on to a existing button in the Magento Admin. When you press capture it shout ask if you are sure. I have found the code of the button in the adminhtml folder and dont know further. I have found out that you can use the onclick parameter to start a js function but that parameter is already set by magento.
Here is the code of the button

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction('capture') && $this->getInvoice()->canCapture()) {
        $this->_addButton('capture', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture'),
                'class'     => 'save',
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\''.$this->getCaptureUrl().'\')'
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\''.$this->getCaptureUrl().'\')'`

---

with  `'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getCaptureUrl()}')",`

Answer (score 3):

```
'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('Are you sure you want to do this?', '{$this->getUrl('*/*/delete')}')",
```